# OpenSSH asks for root@hostname password instead of user@hostname password

Tags: permissions, ssh, sudo, password, root

So I have this other desktop PC, that serves as my server, `primesystem` and a laptop as my client, `zerosystem` that is connected to it. They both serve as my `ssh-server` and `ssh-client` respectively, and is connected through an ethernet (not crossover) cable. Both computers have users named as `one`. Thus, I have `one@zerosystem` and `one@primesystem`.

I used to be able to execute a `mpiexec` command in `primesystem`

```
sudo mpiexec -n 6 -hosts zerosystem,primesystem python -m mpi4py helloworld
```

And it would **only** usually prompt for `one@zerosystem`'s password.

**BUT** due to unforeseen circumstances (my WiFi not working) , I had to log-in as root once in my laptop through `sudo su` *(I just deduced that maybe it was because of this `sudo su`, but I'm not entirely sure)*, and it showed `root@zerosystem`, and enter some command to fix my WiFi.

**ONLY AFTER THAT**, did I notice that when I ran the same `mpiexec` command above, OpenSSH would ask for `root@zerosystem`'s password, and not `one@zerosystem`'s!

[image]

I tried entering `one`'s password, but it says `Permission denied, please try again.` I have another user, namely `zero`, so I tried entering its password too, but it still says the same.

In a little searching, I found a command named `sudo passwd`, where it says that it changes the `root`'s password, and it prompts `Enter new UNIX password:` when initiated. I entered a new password there, and used **THE SAME** password to the OpenSSH's prompt for `root@zerosystem`'s password (the picture above), but it still says permission denied . . . .

What exactly happened? Did `sudo su` somehow triggered a superuser authorization that overrides other user's privileges, and that it must be only `root`'s password that must be entered? Also why did changing the password of `root` **not seem to change the password at all?**

**NOTE:** I can log-in to both hosts through SSH, (`ssh zerosystem` and `ssh primesystem`) but whenever I do a command that somehow acesses `zerosystem`'s files, the prompt for `root@zerosystem` always shows up.

**PS.** I also tried generating another set of SSH keys for both `zerosystem` and `primesystem`, as indicated by [Step 3 in here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/), but to no avail. Somehow, only `primesystem` cannot import/copy the ssh-id due to the `root@zerosystem` prompt.

Comment: what is your local `~/.ssh/config`? Post debug log from your command. It should give you a clue.